# Internet Explorer 9 policy setting is affecting window.postMessage

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a `window.postMessage` in a JavaScript file. This appears to be failing in IE9 because of some policy settings. I can't figure out which policy it is. Does anyone have any ideas which one it could be?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I will put a bounty on this question because I can't figure out whats the problem in our policy.

Comment: Does just your example fail, or do all the `postMessage()` demos on the internet fail too?

Comment: It's the same origin policy http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/04/03/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-2-limited-write.aspx not sure you can change this.

Comment: hey guys, this example here doesn't work in our internal IE9:http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage
it works in any other IE9 I have installed though

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the key you are looking for is:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_CROSS_DOCUMENT_MESSAGING

If the above mentioned registry key is set then IE (all versions from what I can tell) will return undefined for the window.postMessage function.

Comment: Thanks. I just figured this out. In the Group Policy Editor, look for Windows Components / Internet Explorer / Security Features / AJAX and remove the "Enabled" flag from "Turn Off Cross Document Messaging"

Comment: The option was originally added back when almost *every* new IE feature had an option to disable it. (The general idea was that if there was an exploit discovered, it could be surgically neutered without requiring the user to disable JavaScript). In later IE versions, the team backed away with providing policy-controlled “kill switches” for new features, even big ones like WebGL in IE11. This policy really shouldn’t ever be set.

Answer (score 3):

Let me further elaborate outside the comments. As you can see here:

http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

If I use a normal IE9 at home or the one at browserstack.com, the message loads fine inside the iframe. If I use our Intranet IE9 however, I get the following error in JS Console:

```
SCRIPT16385: Not implemented

cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage, line 1 character 1
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
all.js, line 1 character 1
```

It would seem to be some security setting that's preventing the postMessage call.