# Problems with window.postMessage on ie9 and ie10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with window.postMessage in IE9 and IE10, it shows "not implemented" error.

I am trying to post message from iframe page to parent page:

```
try{
  window.postMessage(some_data, parent_url, parent);
}catch(e){
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer 9 policy setting is affecting window.postMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962032/internet-explorer-9-policy-setting-is-affecting-window-postmessage)

Comment: the third parameter is not supported in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: Did you tried http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/ ?This should work fine in IE9/10